# Automate a batch file to answer yes

Tags: batch-file

I want to connect on a remote server and copy a folder that is in location `C:\vrs` and to rename it with the name and sysdate.`

**The script is :**

```
telnet 10.194.32.xxx
copy C:\vrs\vsn C:vrs\vsn_bkup_%Date:~-10,2%_%Date:~-7,2%_%Date:~-4,4%
exit
```

But the issue is that when is connecting on IP, I receive the following question:

```
you are about to send your password information to a remote computer in Internet zone. This might not be safe. Do you want to send it anyway?
```

I have to answer yes, but will not follow the next steps from my bat file.
Can I automate the answer "y" with a new line on the script?

P.S. Neither `echo y| telnet ip` nor `echo y.txt file` work

Any idea? (The server where I want to connect via telnet is Windows 2003 Server R2)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try another telnet client ? [PUTTY](http://www.putty.org/) might be a good choise ...

Comment: what is the title of the window where the Y needs to be sent.  Once we know that, we could in theory issue the sendkeys command from batch via powershell one-liner, kinda like this example - http://superuser.com/questions/696467/can-i-turn-caps-on-of-from-a-batch-file-in-win-7/696477#696477    ---- otherwise, I was thinking of adding that 10.194 host to a more trusted zone which may or may not suppress that dialog.

Comment: you can check this scriptable telnet tool: http://ss64.net/tst10.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to disable NTLM authentication and switch to use only password authentication, for this use tlntadmin command:
tlntadmn config sec=-NTLM 
(you need to be admin on server for this of course)

Comment: This worked!Thanks a lot! But now, I have to automate the script to enter the password itself..for user I typed : telnet -l user ip ..but for password?

Comment: i would not pass password directly, you could use something like send/expect commands for this inside your script

Comment: I want to pass the password with my input on the line command because the security it s not a problem..

Answer (score 1):

Windows `telnet.exe` is not scriptable and it doesn't give you that error message either AFAICS.

`Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0 by Albert Yale` is a free scriptable Telnet client.

To copy a file from a PC on the local LAN then you would use something like this:
(using `%date%` is unreliable as the date format can change from PC to PC)

```
copy "\\server\share\file.txt" "c:\vrs\vsn_bkup_%Date:~-10,2%_%Date:~-7,2%_%Date:~-4,4%"
```

To copy a file from the internet you need other techniques.

Comment: Hello foxidrive,  I don't want to copy a file from pc on the local, I want to connect on the ip like in example and there to make a backup of a file and after rename the backup folder with the date.